# sp_configure: Preserve values of 'xp_cmdshell' and 'Show Advanced Options'

Tags: sql-server, scripting, type-conversion

I dont want to disturb the server values of xp_CMDShell & Show Advanced options. The criteria is to use SQL to run a batch file.

This is the script i am trying to solve it with:

```
DECLARE @advanced_options int
DECLARE @xp_cmdshell int

--CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )

SELECT @advanced_options = value_in_use 
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'show advanced options'

SELECT @xp_cmdshell = value_in_use 
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'xp_cmdshell'

select @advanced_options as advOptions, @xp_cmdshell as cmdShell

exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
Reconfigure;

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_CMDShell', 1;
Reconfigure;

DECLARE @CMDSQL VARCHAR(1000)
SET @CMDSQL = 'F:\Adress\FillDBWithMSTabFiles'--Keep in mind, path needs to be correct.
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell @CMDSQL

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_CMDShell', @xp_cmdshell;
Reconfigure;

exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', @advanced_options;
Reconfigure;

select @advanced_options as advOptions, @xp_cmdshell as cmdShell
```

Results in error:

```
Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 4
Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 8
Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is at below select statements. If you do `ALT+F1` on sys.confiugrations you'll notice that `value_in_use` column is of type sql_variant and you are trying to assign it to int variables. To fix this, use below statements in your script and it should work fine.

```
SELECT @advanced_options = cast(value_in_use as int)
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'show advanced options'

SELECT @xp_cmdshell = cast(value_in_use  as int)
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'xp_cmdshell'
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally put the original values in temp table and then once done with the script/task, I revert it back.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xp_cmdshelloption') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #xp_cmdshelloption;

CREATE TABLE #xp_cmdshelloption (
    configuration_id INT
    ,NAME NVARCHAR(35)
    ,original_value SQL_VARIANT
    )

INSERT INTO #xp_cmdshelloption (
    configuration_id
    ,NAME
    ,original_value
    )
SELECT configuration_id
    ,NAME
    ,value_in_use
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE configuration_id IN (
        518 -- show advanced options
        ,16390 -- xp_cmdshell
        )

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #xp_cmdshelloption
        WHERE original_value = 0
            AND configuration_id = 518
        )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'xp_cmdshell show advanced option is set to 0 ... setting it to 1'

    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options'
        ,1;

    RECONFIGURE
    WITH OVERRIDE;
END

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #xp_cmdshelloption
        WHERE original_value = 0
            AND configuration_id = 16390
        )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'xp_cmdshell option is set to 0 ... setting it to 1'

    EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell'
        ,1;

    RECONFIGURE
    WITH OVERRIDE;
END

PRINT '---------- do your stuff here '
PRINT '---------- stuff done'

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #xp_cmdshelloption
        WHERE original_value = 0
            AND configuration_id = 16390
        )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'reverting back xp_cmdshell value to 0 ..THE ORIGINAL VALUE ..!'

    EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell'
        ,0;

    RECONFIGURE
    WITH OVERRIDE;
END

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #xp_cmdshelloption
        WHERE original_value = 0
            AND configuration_id = 518
        )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'reverting back show advanced options value to 0 ..THE ORIGINAL VALUE ..!'

    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options'
        ,0;

    RECONFIGURE
    WITH OVERRIDE;
END
```

Depending on what you are doing with `xp_cmdshell` calling a `.bat` file, you should look into using PowerShell as an alternative.